# Issue Including Firestore In Flutter App

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I went through this codelab to integrate Google Firestore into my Flutter app but adding:

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.7.3
```

in my pubspec.yaml file breaks the app when I try to run it with

```
flutter run
```

The output of the error is:

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>     is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>     Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

My pubspec.yaml file dependencies are:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker: 0.1.1
  google_sign_in: 0.3.1
  firebase_analytics: 0.0.4
  firebase_auth: 0.2.0
  firebase_database: 0.0.12
  firebase_storage: 0.0.5
  charts_flutter: "^0.2.0"
  cloud_firestore: "^0.7.3"
```

From some research, the issue seems to be something to do with SDK versions being incompatible. How do I go about debugging this issue?